# Flutter for Web - is there any way to implement desktop-like textbox equivalent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'd like to create a simple website with several input fields and one of them needs to accept multiline input. Since I'm learning Flutter anyway I thought it would be a good opportunity to use Flutter for Web for this purpose.

Is there a way to implement a widget similar to traditional textbox?
I have used multiline TextField widget, but it's not the perfect solution from user experience perspective.

Thanks in advance for all hints.

Comment: what is not perfect about it?

Comment: @MahMoos The main issue is text selection, it's behaves in a mobile way

Comment: in that case, I think you should open an issue on the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a `maxLines` attribute like :

```
TextField(
            maxLines: 3,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: allTranslations.text(StringConstant.description),
              ),
            ),
```

then it has more height like a web `textField`

Comment: My main concern is a text selection, especially when text does not fit the TextField, it behaves in mobile way. On the [Flutter for Web Github page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web) I've found the following statement: `At this time, desktop UI interactions are not fully complete, so a UI built with flutter_web may feel like a mobile app, even when running on a desktop browser.` I guess I cannot do anything but wait for further framework development.